# Link repository (community wiki)

Tags: discussion, questions

Would it be appropriate to post a question asking for links to tutorials, tips, and more information about various programming languages?

The beauty of this would be to have the community's favored links all in one place (and very useful for linking future users to).

My vision is to have an answer for most languages. One for HTML, one for CSS, C#, etc. And each could possibly have a subsection for past versions that still have roles in the current ones.

So, would this kind of question be appropriate? Does it already exist?

Comment: The place for this kind of information is the tag wikis. For example, have a look at the [the `css` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info).

Comment: @hammar: Good point...but then wouldn't it be beneficial to have all that *in one place*? That's the whole purpose of this, really--and how often are those tag wikis edited anyways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Generally, link repository questions are shut down as NARQ/NC (can go either way depending on how it's phrased); so  if you're going to ask a question like this *you should ask yourself if you should be asking the question in the first place*.

More often than not, the answer is "no."

Additionally, [community wiki has effectively been depreciated/neutered/made ineffective with the introduction of suggested edits](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).  Again, if you are thinking of making a question/answer community wiki, you should be asking yourself if you really need to do so in the first place.

Again, the answer to that question, more often than not, is "no."